# Zoom on selected svg element using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, zooming

i am working on an application which require Zoom In, Zoom out and Panning. I have achieved all these functionality using viewBox property of svg.

My current Zoom In works fine but it zoom toward the center of screen. I want to add additional functionality of Zoom in toward a selected element. I know i can set viewBox to the selected element bbox values, but i want sequential/smooth zoom in which does not conflict with my current/default zoom in.

how i can achieve this?

here is jsfiddle for the sample code:-
http://jsfiddle.net/55G9c/

***HTML Code***

```
<div onclick="zoomin()" style="display: block;float: left;border: 1px solid;cursor: pointer">
            ZoomIn
        </div>
        <div onclick="zoomout()" style="display: block;float: left;border: 1px solid;cursor: pointer;margin-left: 10px">
            ZoomOut
        </div>
        <svg id="mainsvg" width="600px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 600 500">
        <g id="gnode">
        <rect id="boundry" x="0" y="0" width="599" height="499" fill="none" stroke='black'/>
        <circle id="centernode" cx="300" cy="250" r="5" fill="red" stroke="none" />
        <rect id="selected" x="450" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" stroke='none'/>
        </g>
        </svg>
```

***Javascript Code***

```
var svg=document.getElementById('mainsvg');
            var gnode=document.getElementById('gnode');
            var zoomPercentage=0.25;
            var MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT = 1400;
            var baseBox={};
            var level=0;
            var widthRatio,heightRatio;
            var clientheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var clientwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

            function setup(){
                var

                baseX,
                baseY,
                baseWidth,
                baseHeight,
                percentageDifference,
                heightDifference;

                svg.setAttribute('height', clientheight);
                svg.setAttribute('width', clientwidth);

                var boundry=document.getElementById('boundry');
                boundry.setAttribute('height', clientheight-1);
                boundry.setAttribute('width', clientwidth-1);

                var centernode=document.getElementById('centernode');
                centernode.setAttribute('cy', clientheight/2);
                centernode.setAttribute('cx', clientwidth/2);

                if (svg.height.baseVal.value >= MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT)
                    baseHeight = MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT;
                else
                    baseHeight = Math.round(gnode.getBBox().height) + 60;

                baseY = (svg.height.baseVal.value - baseHeight) / 2;
                percentageDifference = baseHeight / svg.height.baseVal.value;
                baseWidth = percentageDifference * svg.width.baseVal.value;
                baseX = (svg.width.baseVal.value - baseWidth) / 2;


                baseBox.x = baseX;
                baseBox.y = baseY;
                baseBox.width = baseWidth;
                baseBox.height = baseHeight;
                level = 0;

                heightDifference = MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT - baseHeight;
                zoomPercentage = (heightDifference / 10) / heightDifference;                                

                setViewBox(baseBox);
            }
            function setViewBox(viewBox) {
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = Math.round(viewBox.x);
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = Math.round(viewBox.y);
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = Math.round(viewBox.width);
                svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = Math.round(viewBox.height);
                setRatios();
            }
            function setRatios () {
                widthRatio = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width / svg.width.baseVal.value;
                heightRatio = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height / svg.height.baseVal.value;
            }
            function calculateViewBox(level) {

                var
                height = baseBox.height - (zoomPercentage * level * baseBox.height),
                y = baseBox.y + (baseBox.height - height) / 2,
                width = baseBox.width - (zoomPercentage * level * baseBox.width),
                x = baseBox.x + (baseBox.width - width) / 2,
                viewBox = {
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    width: width,
                    height: height
                }
                return viewBox;
            }

            function zoomin(){               
                level++;
                if(level>5)
                    level=5;
                 var
                                x,
                                y,
                                paperViewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal,
                                previousViewBox = calculateViewBox(level - 1),
                                newViewBox = calculateViewBox(level);
                                //callback = this.afterZoom;

                                if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) > Math.round(newViewBox.x))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned left
                                         */
                                        x = paperViewBox.x - (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) / 2;
                                else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) < Math.round(previousViewBox.x) - (Math.round(newViewBox.x) - Math.round(previousViewBox.x)))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned right
                                         */
                                        x = paperViewBox.x + (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) + (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) / 2;
                                else
                                        x = newViewBox.x;

                                if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) > Math.round(newViewBox.y))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned up
                                         */
                                        y = paperViewBox.y - (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) / 2;
                                else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) < Math.round(previousViewBox.y) - (Math.round(newViewBox.y) - Math.round(previousViewBox.y)))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned down
                                         */
                                        y = paperViewBox.y + (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) + (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) / 2;
                                else
                                        y = newViewBox.y;


                                var data = {
                                        viewBox: {
                                                x: x,
                                                y: y,
                                                width: newViewBox.width,
                                                height: newViewBox.height
                                        }
                                }

                                SetZoomViewBox(data);
            }

            function SetZoomViewBox(data){               
                        var viewBox = data.viewBox;

                        svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = Math.round(viewBox.x);
                        svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = Math.round(viewBox.y);
                        svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = Math.round(viewBox.width);
                        svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = Math.round(viewBox.height);
                        setRatios();

            }

            function zoomout(){
                level--;
                if(level<0)
                    level=0;
                 var
                                x,
                                y,
                                paperViewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal,
                                previousViewBox = calculateViewBox(level + 1),
                                newViewBox = calculateViewBox(level);

                                if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) > Math.round(previousViewBox.x) + (Math.round(previousViewBox.x) - Math.round(newViewBox.x)))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned left
                                         */
                                        x = paperViewBox.x - (newViewBox.width - previousViewBox.width);
                                else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) < Math.round(previousViewBox.x))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned right
                                         */
                                        x = paperViewBox.x;
                                else
                                        x = newViewBox.x;

                                if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) > Math.round(previousViewBox.y) + (Math.round(previousViewBox.y) - Math.round(newViewBox.y)))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned up
                                         */
                                        y = paperViewBox.y - (newViewBox.height - previousViewBox.height);
                                else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) < Math.round(previousViewBox.y))
                                        /**
                                         * is panned down
                                         */
                                        y = paperViewBox.y;
                                else
                                        y = newViewBox.y;


                                var data = {
                                        viewBox: {
                                                x: x,
                                                y: y,
                                                width: newViewBox.width,
                                                height: newViewBox.height
                                        }
                                }

                                SetZoomViewBox(data);
            }

            setup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](https://jwatt.org/svg/tests/zoom-and-pan-controlsViewBox.svg) that shows an SVG file with a zoom/pan control.

It sets the currentScale and currentTranslate attributes on the SVG root element to perform zooming/panning.

try running on firefox. click the center green circle to zoom out and red circle to zoom in. Probably you'll get some idea.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but thats not what i am looking for, i already achieved zoom pan using vieBox, kindly read question above

Comment: I tried... you don't have to minus vote my answer. :(

Comment: @xK0nB1n I did -1 because it is obvious that you didn't even read the title of the question, let alone the text of the question which does already has a solution for the task you try to solve with your question.

Comment: @tobltobs I'll try again :) I posted the zoom in and zoom out functionality to give him some idea. I guess you wanted me to post a exact answer.

Comment: I up voted the answer, down voted the question. RashFlash, perhaps your question is to unclear. And its really lame to down vote answers from people who atleast did try to answer your unclear question?

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus thanks for making SO a better place. Cheers

Comment: Something is wrong with your sample @xxbinxx get lots of console errors